# How to save a ByteArray from Flex into a FileField in Django

Tags: django, apache-flex, django-models, arrays, filefield

I have some audio data in a byte array in a Flex app that I would like to save to my model in Django. I assume I would use a FileField, but I can't seem to get it to work. (My project is set up [like this](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex_django.html).) I've tried looking at this [sample code for PyAmf](http://www.pyamf.org/tutorials/actionscript/bytearray.html), but I can't quite get the two to combine.

If anyone has a bit of code to share, that would be lovely!

Answer (score 0):

Django's FileFields are not blobs - they only store the path to where the data is saved on the filesystem. You will need to save the data to disk and put the path into the FileField.

Comment: Ok -- good to know. I guess my next question would be: What's the best way to save a local ByteArray to Django? I've found this: http://blog.joa-ebert.com/2006/05/01/save-bytearray-to-file-with-php/ but it uses php. (Thanks for the help by the way -- I'm quite new to this, as you may have guessed.)